# ORA:12154 error in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, odbc, dsn, ora-12154

I have an excel file which was developed by my predecessor and which uses external data connection to fetch data from Oracle.

I am trying to migrate this file to a new client PC and I am getting the following error while refreshing the data:

**ora 12154 tns could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

The connection is established via DSN and TNS reference. The system specifications are as:

OS: Windows 7 64 bit
Oracle Client: Oracle 10.2.0 32 bit.
DSN Created in the 32 bit odbcad32.exe

TNSNames.ora is as under:

> ODS_BKUP =   (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS_LIST =
>         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.146.64.132)(PORT = 1521))
>       )
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SID = ODSDB)
>       )   )

I am able to do Test connection succesfully from the DSN. TNS ping also working for the server. But when I refresh the data in excel, I am getting the error.

Connection String Given in excel

> DSN=MP_Prod;UID=ODS_MPMON;PWD=ODS_MPMON;DBQ=ODS_BKUP;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

same problem here and this is the solution:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/277836-excel-2010-ora-12154-tns-could-not-resolve-service-name

Hope this help you! =)
Ale.